# How to improve my python code to speed it up?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Below is my current code:

```
import pandas as pd
import math
import csv

fund = 10000
print("investment",fund)

pval = 0
oldportfolio = []

dts = ["06 Feb 2017", "07 Feb 2017", "08 Feb 2017", "09 Feb 2017", "10 Feb 2017", "13 Feb 2017", "14 Feb 2017", "15 Feb 2017", "16 Feb 2017", "17 Feb 2017",
        "20 Feb 2017", "21 Feb 2017", "22 Feb 2017", "23 Feb 2017", "27 Feb 2017"]
for dt in dts:
    files = ["stocklistcustom.csv"]
    for file in files:
        df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None)
        i = 0
        filecount = len(df)
        result = []
        while i < filecount:
        # while i < 10:
            name = df[0][i]
            link = df[1][i]
            mcsym = df[2][i]
            i = i + 1
            filepath = "data/nse/his/" + mcsym + ".csv"
            try:
                sp = pd.read_csv(filepath, header=None)
                endrow = sp[sp[0] == dt].index[0] + 1
                parray = []
                tarray = []
                starray = []
                intdate = []
                p1 = 0
                p2 = 0
                p3 = 0
                p4 = 0
                j = 0
                mavg15 = ''
                mavg60 = ''
                olddiff = 0
                days = 2
                strtrow = endrow - days - 60
                for k in range (strtrow, endrow):
                    date = sp[0][k]
                    price = float(sp[4][k])
                    k = k + 1
                    parray.append(price)
                    j = j + 1
                    strtavg = j - 15
                    mavg15 = sum(parray[strtavg:j]) / 15
                    strtavg = j - 60
                    mavg60 = sum(parray[strtavg:j]) / 60
                    # buy criteria
                    if j > 59:
                        diff = mavg60 - mavg15
                        if diff < 0 and olddiff > 0:
                            trigger = 1
                            intdate.append(date)
                        else:
                            trigger = 0
                        tarray.append(trigger)
                        olddiff = diff
                    # sell criteria
                    if j == (days + 60):
                        pricep = (price - p1) * 100 / p1
                        p1p = (p1 - p2) * 100 / p2
                        p2p = (p2 - p3) * 100 / p3
                        p3p = (p3 - p4) * 100 / p4
                        if pricep < -5 or pricep > 8:
                            sell = 1
                        if price < p1 and p1 < p2 and p2 < p3:
                            sell = 1
                        else:
                            sell = 0
                    p4 = p3
                    p3 = p2
                    p2 = p1
                    p1 = price
                if sum(tarray) > 0:
                    result.append([name,mcsym,"buy",price])
                if sell > 0:
                    result.append([name,mcsym,"sell",price])
            except:
                # print(name,"not found")
                pass

    # print(result)

    output = "output/triggers/"+dt+"trigger.csv"
    with open(output, "wb") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(result)
        print(output,"exported")
```

The above code create an array named result and exports various csv files with calls...

The code below now process the data in result array to compute portfolio value

```
    # Code for calculating investment
    portfolio = []
    for row in result:
        if row[2] == "sell" and len(oldportfolio) > 0:
            pindex = 0
            for buys in oldportfolio:
                bindex = 0
                for stock in buys:
                    if row[0] == stock[0]:
                        sellqty = stock[2]
                        sellp = row[3]
                        sellval = sellqty * sellp
                        purchasep = stock[1]
                        sellcost = purchasep * sellqty
                        print(dt,"selling",row[0],row[1],sellp,sellqty,sellval)
                        # print(oldportfolio)
                        del oldportfolio[pindex][bindex]
                        # print(oldportfolio)
                        fund = fund + sellval
                        pval = pval - sellcost
                    bindex = bindex + 1
                pindex = pindex + 1
    # print("op", oldportfolio)
    # print(dt,"fund after selling",fund)
    buycount = sum(1 for row in result if row[2]==("buy"))
    if buycount > 0:
        maxinvest = fund / buycount
    for row in result:
        if row[2] == "buy":
            name = row[0]
            price = row[3]
            qty = math.floor(maxinvest / price)
            if qty > 0:
                val = qty * price
                print(dt,"buying",name,row[1],price,qty,val)
                portfolio.append([name,price,qty,val])
                fund = fund - val

    # print("portfolio",portfolio)
    pval = pval + sum(row[3] for row in portfolio)
    print(dt,"cash",fund,"portfolio value",pval,"total",fund+pval)
    oldportfolio.append(portfolio)

print(oldportfolio)
```

It gives me the value of portfolio for each day after trading based on certain rules. But its execution time is too much. How to reduce its execution time?

Also, I need to change pval as it is calculated incorrectly in current code. It must be calculated based on that particular day's prices.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Moved this question to codereview as suggested.

Answer (score -1):

Your code has multiple nested loops which probably why it is so slow.

But your biggest problem isn't speed, it's readability. It is really hard to reason about your code, consider refactoring.

I'm sure you'll find some bottlenecks and be able to improve your code while refactoring.

Comment: What is refactoring?

Comment: Basically restructuring code to make it more readable.
(read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring)
Try to split your code into smaller functions.

Comment: Wikipedia won't be of much help here. It doesn't describe the topic appropriately, rather talks about it in an encyclopedic manner. I have tried to split the code in question into two parts. Is this what you were talking about?